# Create styled grid with phaserJS gaming framework

Tags: grid, phaser, html

I am new to Phaser and this is my first game with Phaser gaming framework. Am trying to find the right way of coding a grid what you see in below image

[image]

In some articles is being suggested to code it with html and place it over the canvas but in that case am having issues when resizing the screen.

Any ideas how i can achieve such type of grids creation. I cant have it as a full image cause there are animations per each winning case and that current winning symbol is being highlighted with the points.

Thanks.